# EmguCV never open ".jpg" file but open only ".tif" files..Why?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am using **EmguCV in Visual Studio 2022** and I am simple trying to read and open my image but it only opens **.tif** image files not **.jpg** or any other file...
When I try to open any **.jpg** file it gives me an exception **openCV:index out of bound**

Here:

[image]

I also debugged it and find something like it is not reading file when I passed it to EmguCV image structure "**Image<Bgr,byte> imgFile=new Image<Bgr,byte>(filename)**"
while it is loading file from dialogue but not passing forward from this structure.
**Here's the Debug SS:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Emgu;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
namespace test_EmguCV
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Image<Bgr, byte> imgFile = new Image<Bgr, byte>(ofd.FileName);
                pictureBox1.Image = imgFile.Bitmap;

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void exToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

**Another Imp:**
***My friend is also doing the same work with me and he is using the same ide same mehtods same references same dll files but his is running fine but not of mine..***

Comment: Maybe your friend has different images?

Comment: Your screenshot is showing an attempt to load a PNG file, but your title talks about JPGs. Anyway: what if you remove the try/catch and look at the uncaught exception in your debugger? It would likely show you more detail than just that.

Comment: Also the file as a filename with spaces....what if you just give the file a simple name like `testpic.png`

Comment: I have read all of your comments now check again I have edited it and also checked according you asked..

Comment: @ThomasWeller no he is using screen shots while and I have used them too images downloaded from internet but problems remains the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code snippet in a new Form and I can say that I can successfully load a .jpg image and display it in a PictureBox. Make sure your image is not corrupted in the first place.

Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Image<Bgr, byte> imgFile = new Image<Bgr, byte>(ofd.FileName);
                    pictureBox1.Image = imgFile.ToBitmap();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Note that it's `imgFile.ToBitmap()`, not `imgFile.Bitmap()`

Also I would suggest you to switch to `Mat` instead of `Image<>`. [More info from OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html)

With `Mat` the code to get the image is as easy as:

```
Mat imgFile = new Mat(ofd.FileName);
```

[More info about Mat in EmguCV here](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.1/document/html/2ec33afb-1d2b-cac1-ea60-0b4775e4574c.htm)

Comment: still giving exception that **parameter is not valid**

Comment: Please explain better the exception and which parameter is giving you this issue

Comment: Bro! I installed vs2019 and it all works fine but on vs 2022 it doesn't work bro!! Well thanks for help...